# Gathering and outputting data by selector of database column

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I am creating a forum and the code I am putting in this thread is the page that shows all of the forum categories. I have this setup where I have an id, category_section, category_title, and category_description. The way it is structured now is that it creates a new category section border every time I add a new category title in my database. This is what I mean by this:

As an example:

My category section is called Shoes, my category titles are Nike, Adidas, Reebok

Currently, it does:

```
Shoes
Nike
Shoes
Adidas
Shoes
Reebok
```

But it should do this:

```
Shoes
Nike
Adidas
Reebok
```

How can I get my current code to do this?

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM forum_categories ORDER BY category_title DESC");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$categories = "";
if($numrows > 0){
    while($forum_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $categoryid = $forum_row['id'];
        $category_section = $forum_row['category_section'];
        $categoryTitle = $forum_row['category_title'];
        $categoryDescription = $forum_row['category_description'];
        $categories = "<a href='forum_view_category.php?cid=".$categoryid."'>"
            . $categoryTitle . "</a>";
        //$categories .= "<a href='forum_view_category.php?cid=".$categoryid
        //."' class='cat_links'>" . $categoryTitle . "</a>" " - " . $categoryDescription .;
?>
<div class="category_section">
    <?php echo $category_section; ?>
</div>
<div class="category_border">
    <div class="discussions_left">
        <div class="discussions_category_title">
            <?php echo $categories; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="discussions_category_description">
            <?php echo $categoryDescription; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="discussions_right">
    </div>
</div>  
<?php
    }
    //echo $categories;
} else {
    echo "<p>There are no posted categories available yet. </p>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your SQL to order by section first, then the title.

```sql
SELECT * FROM forum_categories ORDER BY category_section DESC, category_title DESC
```

After you've done that, define an `if` statement to check if the current section is the same as the previous statement.

- If so, move one.
- If not, echo the new section title.

I've cleaned up your code a bit and switched to the [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for readability and maintainability.

[PHPFiddle Demo <sup><sub>(faked MySQL)</sub></sup>](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/zvwk-3eu5)

```php
<?php
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM forum_categories ORDER BY category_section DESC, category_title DESC");
    $category_section = "";
?>
<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0): ?>
    <?php while($cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)): ?>
        <?php if($cat['category_section'] !== $category_section): ?>
            <?php $category_section = $cat['category_section'] ?>
            <div class="category_section">
                <?= $category_section ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>         
        <div class="category_border">
            <div class="discussions_left">
                <div class="discussions_category_title">
                    <a href="forum_view_category.php?cid=<?= $cat['id'] ?>">
                        <?= $cat['category_title'] ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="discussions_category_description">
                    <?= $cat['category_description'] ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="discussions_right">
            </div>
        </div> 
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>There are no posted categories available yet.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This is only displaying one of the category titles from the category sections.

Comment: Are there any errors? Is it only display one for each section or it only displaying one total? Or were you using the code before I updated? Try the current code again and if it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: It is the current update. I saw you updated it right before I tried it. I have multiple category titles per category section and in each category section it only displays one of the titles. No errors. Say I had shoes (nike/adidas), phones (apple/Samsung). It is showing SHOES nike, PHONES apple.

Comment: I've updated the code above (fixed a couple minor errors), but it should work. See this [demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/zvwk-3eu5).

Comment: Thanks! Quick question. Why did you change the format? Why aren't fetched variables cleaner and more readable?

Comment: Less code, and the use of the Alternative syntax is preferred when interacting with HTML. The general idea is to not have HTML within strings being echo-ed by PHP. For readability and maintainability (and scalability) reasons, the alternative syntax is just easier to follow. And calling the variable directly instead of caching it just means less lines of code. You cache objects that take time to create. Because the array has already been created, you're actually using more memory assigning the value of each item in an array to a new variable instead of calling it directly.